# Wrapper datatype to store YEAR alone

Tags: java, types, wrapper

I just want to store year value( for example 2011 or 2020) in a wrapper datatype. Which is the best suggested datatype? Is Integer wrapper type enough?

Comment: Yes. Those values would fit in a `short` too.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [the `Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class, which is part of the JDK since Java 8? That way you also get a few useful methods for free (such as `isLeap`, `length`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Integer class it can save same as int
you can see the max value by using Integer.MAX_VALUE